# strace -T accuracy, how to measure system call timing?

Tags: linux, performance, strace

I'm trying to measure how much time is spent for a particular system call of the running process. Running `strace -T` shows timing of all system calls, but the question is if the time is accurate. Does `strace` introduce the overhead for the system call itself and without strace I should expect the system call to perform faster.

Comment: it shouldnt introduce overhead. You can check implementation, https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/3fedf07869e605841a70b4387f0b5ba44c073cf1/strace.c#LL2409C1-L2409C14. The trace_syscall function is called after and before calling systemcalls.